# Pandas Datframe sort_values on binary data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas, I have a dataframe that I would sort with binary data so that the data is separated between the 0's and 1's. I am using `df.sort_values`, will `df.sort_values` sort the data the same way every time?

EDIT: 
here is an example of the data frame that I use:
[image]

I would like to sort from the data frame from the second column.

here is the code I use:

```
sort_data = df.sort_values(['Diagnosis'],axis=0,ascending=True)
```

Comment: add a dataframe as text to demonstrate the problem please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answerer is: it depends on your sorting algorithm.

There exists *stable* and *unstable* sorting algorithms. `sort_values` supports merge sort, which is stable, but has a default algorithm (`quick sort`) that is unstable. A stable sorting algorithm keeps the output of elements with same key in their same order as they were in the input.

From the [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html),

> kind : {‘quicksort’, ‘mergesort’, ‘heapsort’}, default ‘quicksort’
>
> Choice of sorting algorithm. See also ndarray.np.sort for more
>   information. **mergesort is the only stable algorithm**. For DataFrames,
>   this option is only applied when sorting on a single column or label.

Therefore, if you pick a stable algorithm, it *will* sort the data in the same way every time. It is good to know, however, the limitations of the sorting algorithms you use. There some [nice sources](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-better-mergesort/) available online.